# Capture text from YouTube search box in android

Tags: java, android

How to capture text from YouTube search bar in android using accessibility service or any other technique so that i can identify what type of keyword is being searched on youtube

I have tried it doing using accessibility services but not able to do it. Any other method would be appreciated

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am trying to get text typed in YouTube search bar using the accessibility service android

Answer (score 0):

You can't intercept the native Youtube App, if you intended to do that. Instead, provide your own search box to your App and make the search request via API. Then you have full control over it.